# PHP returning question marks for ls command

Tags: java, php, linux, apache, permissions

I've been having this problem for about a week now. However, it only seems to be on this server that I get all these errors. I've tried re-installing the OS multiple times with different partitions and the exact same thing is happening. Now, I have no idea why its happening.

The problem is that, for some reason, when running the command `ls` PHP returns alot of question marks for the file/directory permissions and owners. For example, when running the command `ls -al /` this is whats returned:

```
total 96
dr-xr-xr-x.  25 root root  4096 Oct 14 12:52 .
dr-xr-xr-x.  25 root root  4096 Oct 14 12:52 ..
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root     0 Oct 14 12:45 .autofsck
dr-xr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Oct 14 13:12 bin
d??????????   ? ?    ?        ?            ? boot
drwxr-xr-x.  17 root root  3740 Oct 14 12:46 dev
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Oct 14 12:52 downloads
drwxr-xr-x. 102 root root 12288 Oct 14 13:12 etc
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Sep 23  2011 home
dr-xr-xr-x.  11 root root  4096 Oct 14 12:41 lib
dr-xr-xr-x.   9 root root 12288 Oct 14 13:11 lib64
d??????????   ? ?    ?        ?            ? lost+found
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Sep 23  2011 media
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root     0 Oct 14 12:46 misc
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Sep 23  2011 mnt
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root     0 Oct 14 12:46 net
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root  4096 Oct 14 12:41 opt
dr-xr-xr-x. 225 root root     0 Oct 14 12:45 proc
d??????????   ? ?    ?        ?            ? root
dr-xr-xr-x.   2 root root 12288 Oct 14 13:12 sbin
drwxr-xr-x.   7 root root     0 Oct 14 12:45 selinux
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Sep 23  2011 srv
drwxr-xr-x.  13 root root     0 Oct 14 12:45 sys
drwxrwxrwt.   5 root root  4096 Oct 14 13:11 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.  13 root root  4096 Oct 14 12:37 usr
drwxr-xr-x.  22 root root  4096 Oct 14 12:52 var
```

Understandably, the directories `/root` and `/lost+found` return question marks because the permissions for them don't allow read and execute for all users (such as drwx------.). However, the directory `/boot` also returns question marks despite the permission for it allowing reading and executing from all users (`dr-xr-xr-x.`).

This becomes more problematic when I run commands such as `screen` (GNU Screen). Screen requires the use of a directory located at `/var/run/screen`. Unfortunately, every time you run screen from PHP, it returns saying `Cannot make directory '/var/run/screen': File exists`. When running screen through SSH it works as expected.

When running the command `ls -al /var/run` through PHP to check the permissions of the directory, it returns this:

```
total 48
drwxr-xr-x. 23 root  root   4096 Oct 14 12:52 .
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root  root   4096 Oct 14 12:52 ..
d??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? ConsoleKit
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root   4096 Oct 14 12:46 abrt
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root      5 Oct 14 12:46 abrtd.pid
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? acpid.pid
s??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? acpid.socket
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? atd.pid
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? auditd.pid
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? autofs-running
p??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? autofs.fifo-misc
p??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? autofs.fifo-net
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? autofs.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root   4096 Feb 22  2013 certmonger
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? certmonger.pid
d??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? console
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? console-kit-daemon.pid
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? cron.reboot
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? crond.pid
d??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? cups
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? cupsd.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root   4096 Oct 14 12:46 dbus
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root   4096 Feb 21  2013 faillock
d??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? hald
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? haldaemon.pid
drwx--x---.  2 root  apache 4096 Oct 14 13:04 httpd
d??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? lvm
d??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? mdadm
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? messagebus.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2 mysql mysql  4096 Oct 14 12:52 mysqld
drwxrwxr-x.  2 root  root   4096 Feb 22  2013 netreport
d??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? plymouth
d??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? pm-utils
d??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? portreserve
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? rpc.statd.pid
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? rpcbind.lock
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? rpcbind.pid
s??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? rpcbind.sock
d??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? saslauthd
d??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? screen
d??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? sepermit
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root   4096 May 10 05:06 setrans
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? sm-notify.pid
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? sshd.pid
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? syslogd.pid
-??????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? utmp
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root   4096 Feb 21  2013 winbindd
```

When running the same command through SSH under the user root to cross check the permissions for all the directories this happens:

```
total 164
drwxr-xr-x. 23 root      root      4096 Oct 14 12:52 .
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root      root      4096 Oct 14 12:52 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root      4096 Oct 14 12:46 abrt
-rw-r--r--.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:46 abrtd.pid
-rw-r--r--.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:46 acpid.pid
srw-rw-rw-.  1 root      root         0 Oct 14 12:46 acpid.socket
-rw-r--r--.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:46 atd.pid
-rw-r-----.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:46 auditd.pid
prw-------.  1 root      root         0 Oct 14 12:46 autofs.fifo-misc
prw-------.  1 root      root         0 Oct 14 12:46 autofs.fifo-net
-rw-r--r--.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:46 autofs.pid
----------.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:46 autofs-running
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root      4096 Feb 22  2013 certmonger
-rw-------.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:46 certmonger.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root      4096 Feb 21  2013 console
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root      4096 Oct 14 12:46 ConsoleKit
-rw-r--r--.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:46 console-kit-daemon.pid
-rw-r--r--.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:46 crond.pid
----------.  1 root      root         0 Oct 14 12:46 cron.reboot
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root      lp        4096 Oct 14 12:46 cups
-rw-r--r--.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:46 cupsd.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root      4096 Oct 14 12:46 dbus
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root      4096 Feb 21  2013 faillock
drwx------.  2 haldaemon haldaemon 4096 Jul 19  2011 hald
-rw-r--r--.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:46 haldaemon.pid
drwx--x---.  2 root      apache    4096 Oct 14 13:04 httpd
drwx------.  2 root      root      4096 Feb 22  2013 lvm
drwx------.  2 root      root      4096 Feb 21  2013 mdadm
-rw-r--r--.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:46 messagebus.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2 mysql     mysql     4096 Oct 14 12:52 mysqld
drwxrwxr-x.  2 root      root      4096 Feb 22  2013 netreport
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root      4096 Feb 22  2013 plymouth
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root      root      4096 Oct 14 12:40 pm-utils
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root      4096 Oct 14 12:45 portreserve
-r--r--r--.  1 root      root         0 Oct 14 12:45 rpcbind.lock
-rw-r--r--.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:45 rpcbind.pid
srw-rw-rw-.  1 root      root         0 Oct 14 12:45 rpcbind.sock
-rw-r--r--.  1 rpcuser   rpcuser      5 Oct 14 12:45 rpc.statd.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root      4096 Nov 27  2012 saslauthd
drwxrwxr-x.  2 root      screen    4096 Jul 19  2011 screen
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root      4096 Feb 21  2013 sepermit
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root      4096 May 10 05:06 setrans
-rw-------.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:45 sm-notify.pid
-rw-r--r--.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:46 sshd.pid
-rw-------.  1 root      root         5 Oct 14 12:45 syslogd.pid
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root      utmp      3456 Oct 14 12:47 utmp
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root      4096 Feb 21  2013 winbindd
```

Again, like the `/boot` directory, it seems that the directory, despite having permissions that allow reading and writing for all users (`drwxrwxr-x.` - chmod 0775), returns question marks for the permissions and owners.

I only managed to find one or two questions being asked about this error returned by screen, of which, none were answered. I managed to work out a quick fix for this to get it to work is to delete the `/var/run/screen` directory and to let PHP recreate this by allowing the user to write to the directory `/var/run`. Changing the permissions of the directory does nothing, so does recreating the directory from the root user and making the owner the web server user.

Even though this is a fix, it does not always mean everything will work fine. If I then try to start a JVM (command `java`) inside the screen, this error is returned:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for code cache
```

At this point, I just gave in as I have no clue as to whats happening.

Can anyone shed some light on my situation and try to explain whats happening or provide a fix for me.

The machine this is happening on is a dedicated server running CentoOS 6.4 with 16GB of RAM, a 500gb HDD and an Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 V2 @ 3.30GHz. Using the command `parted` then `print` this is whats returned about the partitions:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD5003AZEX-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  466GB  466GB   primary  ext3            boot
 2      466GB   500GB  34.4GB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
```

PHP isn't running in safe mode.

This is the code I ran to get the `ls` commands, etc. It's run from a web server each time.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

echo `whoami`;
echo "\n";

echo `ls -al /var/run`;
echo "\n";
echo `ls -al /`;
?>
```

Comment: Where is the PHP code that you are using to call `ls`?

Comment: What's your PHP user? Is it the same you logged on via SSH and executed the commands? Maybe `sudo` (if available under CentOS) could help you get the permissions right (you could only require elevated permissions for that single script)?

Comment: @Fleshgrinder The PHP user is `apache`. I log in to SSH using the user `root`. Using the command `su -s /bin/bash apache` to sudo in to the user `apache` and then running the code returns the same as what running the command from the user `root` does.

Comment: Akward, I can't reproduce this on my Debian based servers, I guess I want be from much help here then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was related to `SELinux`. **Disabling** it solved the problem. It's because the process is trying to execute sub-processes.